# How to break the Key/sequence pairs in Spark RDDs into Key/Value pairs?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD in this format:

`(key, [v1, v2, v3, ..., vn])`

and I want to transform it into an RDD like this:

`(key, v1), (key, v2), ..., (key, vn)`

To elaborate more, I use `sc.wholeTextFile(dir)` to read all text documents in `dir` directory and the RDD will be like this: `(document, content)`. I want to transform this into an RDD like this: `(document, word)`. In other words, I want to keep the document information in the RDD.

I use `RDD.flatMap(lambda (document, text): (document, re.split(' '), text))` to split the text into words, but couldn't find a way to break the sequence of words into separate elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scala seems more intuitive with a  **case**. Anyway.

In pyspark:

```
%python
files = sc.wholeTextFiles("/FileStore/tables/x*.txt",0).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1].replace('?',' ').replace('.',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\n',' ')  )) 
wordsAndFile = files.map(lambda k_v: (k_v[0], k_v[1].split(" ")))
res = wordsAndFile.map(lambda k_v: [(k_v[0], x) for x in k_v[1]])
final = res.flatMap(lambda x: x).filter(lambda x: x[1] is not u'')
final.collect()
```

Using 3 files I get this, part shown:

```
Out[129]: [('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'Hi'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'how'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'are'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'you'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'I'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'am'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'fine'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', '3rd'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x1.txt', 'line'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x2.txt', 'John'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x2.txt', 'I'),
('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/x2.txt', 'am'),
...
...
```

Just for merit, the Scala approach with case is easier and less \r, \n stuff. Did not apply replaceAll, just to demonstrate the point:

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("/FileStore/tables/x*.txt",0) 
val lines2 = files.map { case (x, y) =>  (x, y.split(" ")) }
val lines3 = lines2.flatMap {  case (k, v) => { v.map(x => (k,x))    }  }
lines3.collect
```